# How to check the Wlan standard supported in the Network Card?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

How to find out whether the Wlan standard supported and currently activated by the Network Card is 802.11 b/g/n ?

Is there some tool in Windows Vista which provides this information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the adapter settings through network and sharing in the control panel, hit configure at the top and go to the advanced tab it should tell you what modes are available. For mine you can see that N is not available in this list it has it's own separate option called "802.11n mode".

[image]

Comment: No problem, I'm always happy to lend a hand.